# Do we use an article here or we dont?

Tags: articles

> What country are you from **young man**?
>
> - I'm from Englad.

So, in this sentence, do we any article like "the young man" or "a young man"?
By logic i think we must use "the young man".
But i hesitate because in the same book, i saw an example, like:

> Hi, old man! How are you? .... So long old man!

And in this example, they did not use any article.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, **young man** is just a form of address, the same as addressing someone by their name, so an article is not required. There is no logical reason to use *the.* You wouldn't say "Good morning, the Peter."